# Cannot open RDF document IRIs in openlink virtuoso

Tags: rdf, virtuoso

I wanted to learn about RDF and converting relational data to RDF.

I tried to get basic idea about RDF followed by virtuoso-opensource and hence downloaded and tried to do something with it.

---

**AIM:** I thought of taking two csv files and generating rdf and try accessing the relationships through URIs.

---

Here are the **steps** i took:

Logged into *conductor*.

I had 2 csv files, i imported it in *Database/CSV* directory.
I went into *'Linked Data'>'Views'*: Selected 'Qualifier' as CSV and selected the 2 CSV files(csv.dba.csvfile1.csv & csv.dba.csvfile2.csv) and started '*Generate Via Wizard*'.

It automatically detected the primary key.

For *Targets*, I selected all the targets:  *'Data Source Ontology Mappings', 'Instance Data View Mappings', 'VoID statistic'*.

Onto *'Linked Data View Definition'* i selected both, *'Data Source Ontology Rules', 'Instance Data Rules'*.

*'Prepare to Execute'*

*'Execute'*: The execution ended with *'Execution Status'* message 'OK'.

On trying to use the URI's i could not use them but could not.
Error i got,

> Error HTTP/1.1 404 File not found
>
> The requested URL was not found    URI  = '/describe/'

Also, *'SQL Relations (Tables) to RDF Statements (Predicate / Property Graph) Mappings'* shows three links that shows above error as well.

In *'Sample Graph IRIs & Linked Data Entity URIs'* 
i could see any links.

---

Sorry about putting the question badly, i tried to do better but i can feel that its messy and difficult to go through.
I didn't had very strong concepts but, i thought of visualizing it practically while i go through theoretical information.
If i missed anything, please mention and I'll add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573108/cannot-access-rdf-document-named-graph-iris), it seems likely you haven't followed the documentation, [Automated Generation of Linked Data Views over Relational Data Sources with Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRdb2RDFViewsGeneration), and so haven't installed the `cartridges_dav.vad` and `fct_dav.vad` VAD packages, which bring the `/describe/` page which is giving you the `404`.

Note that there are different VAD builds for use with each of [Commercial and Open Source Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/features-comparison-matrix/), and these should generally be matched to the Virtuoso version in use.

- [VADs for Virtuoso v7.2 Commercial Editions](http://opldownload.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=uda/vad-packages/7.2/)
- [VADs for VOS (Virtuoso Open Source) v7.2](http://opldownload.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=uda/vad-vos-packages/7.2/)

ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.