# cannot access RDF Document (Named Graph) IRIs:

Tags: virtuoso

I am trying to learn Virtuoso, and I tried for *'Generating Linked Data Views from Relational Data Sources'*. I got the URN and try executing the SPARQL execution.
with following details:

```
Default Graph IRI: urn:localhost:8890:CSV
Query:
SELECT * 
FROM <urn:sparql:tests:create:data> 
WHERE 
  {
    ?s ?p ?o
  }
```

I got output like this:

```
s                                                        p                                               o
http://localhost:8890/CSV/emp_csv/DEPTNO/1#this         http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/emp_csv
http://localhost:8890/CSV/dept_csv/EMPNO/1#this         http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/dept_csv
http://localhost:8890/CSV/dept_csv/EMPNO/1#this         http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/              7369
http://localhost:8890/CSV/dept_csv/EMPNO/1#this         http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/ename         "smith"
http://localhost:8890/CSV/dept_csv/EMPNO/1#this         http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/job           "clerk"
http://localhost:8890/CSV/emp_csv/DEPTNO/1#this         http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/deptno        10
http://localhost:8890/CSV/dept_csv/EMPNO/1#this         http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/deptno        10
http://localhost:8890/CSV/emp_csv/DEPTNO/1#this         http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/dname         "appserver"
http://localhost:8890/CSV/emp_csv/DEPTNO/1#this         http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/loc           "newyork"
http://localhost:8890/CSV/emp_csv/DEPTNO/1#this         http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/id             1
http://localhost:8890/CSV/dept_csv/EMPNO/1#this         http://localhost:8890/schemas/CSV/id             1
```

Now when i tried to access the links mentioned in above table, i get error. location not found.

> For example if i select:
>   http://localhost:8890/CSV/emp_csv/DEPTNO/1#this
>
> I get the selected link addressed to:
>   http://localhost:8890/about/html/http://localhost:8890/CSV/emp_csv/DEPTNO/1#this
>
> and the page shows:
>   Error HTTP/1.1 404 File not found
>
> The requested URL was not found    URI  =
>   '/about/html/http:/localhost:8890/CSV/emp_csv/DEPTNO/1'

Any help or suggestions are more than welcomed.
Thank you.

Comment: It's helpful to provide a link to the documentation you're following, as rogue copies of official pages don't always track changes, among other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems likely you haven't followed the documentation,  [Automated Generation of Linked Data Views over Relational Data Sources with Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRdb2RDFViewsGeneration), and so haven't installed the `cartridges_dav.vad` and `fct_dav.vad` VAD packages, which bring the `/about/` page which is giving you the `404`.

Note that there are different VAD builds for use with each of [Commercial and Open Source Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/features-comparison-matrix/), and these should generally be matched to the Virtuoso version in use.

- [VADs for Virtuoso v7.2 Commercial Editions](http://opldownload.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=uda/vad-packages/7.2/)
- [VADs for VOS (Virtuoso Open Source) v7.2](http://opldownload.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=uda/vad-vos-packages/7.2/)

ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](https://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), and employs me.